# What are the ways to decrease GAE CPU% usage?

Tags: google-app-engine

What did you do to make sure the CPU% is low?
Any sample code to look at?

I ask because every datastore read/query seems to push the CPU% beyond 100% and I get the yellow & red highlight in my dashboard. I read from else where that it's normal but surely there's something can be done about it.

Comment: Why do you ask?  How is this affecting you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [appstats](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html) to get more detail on any long running tasks.  It does a good job breaking down exactly how the CPU time is spent and lets you drill down individual calls and view the stack to narrow down which command is running long.

Urlfetch's and database calls tend to be expensive.  As [Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712899/what-are-the-ways-to-decrease-gae-cpu-usage/5719965#5719965) suggests, both can be [memcached](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Efficient-model-memcaching) for very significant savings.

[image: appstats w00t]

Answer (score 5):

You profile your code and improve its efficiency.

Answer (score 4):

Datastore operations are expensive. Try reducing their usage with the help of memcache

Answer (score 3):

Is your app restarting a lot?

I notice even a very minimal app will take over 1sec to load when it has been inactive for a while -- which brings up a warning marker in the log.

Answer (score 2):

For pages you can cache you can use cache-control  if you have a request handler.

```
self.response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "public,max-age=%s" % 86400
```

In many cases you also can use a cron job to regularly update your cache.

Answer (score 2):

I've written [a simple library](https://github.com/ocanbascil/Performance-AppEngine) to reduce datastore operations by using local instance and memcache as storage layers along with datastore. It also supports cached GQL results. I managed to cut my apps' CPU usage by 50% at least. You can give it a try if you're not using any sensitive data.